# WooCommerce - Custom cart - How to add AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I coded my own mini-shopping-cart for a website I'm currently working on and it's working fine. Now I need a way to add AJAX to said cart.
Here's the code so far:

```
<div class="custom-cart-container">
    <div class="shopping_cart_link">
        <a class="shopping_cart_link_text" href="http://www.wein-partner.at/wp/cart/"><span class="fa">&#xf07a;</span> ZUM <span class="fat"> WARENKORB</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="shopping_cart_custom">
        <div class="cart_custom_top">
            <a class="cart_preview fa dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> &#xf07a;  &#xf06e;  <a class="sub dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Schnellansicht</a></a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart_custom_bottom">
        <?php
            global $woocommerce;

            // get cart quantity
            $qty = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

            // get cart total
            $total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();

            // get cart url
            $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();

            // if multiple products in cart
            if($qty>1)
                echo '<a href="'.$cart_url.'">'.$qty.' Produkte - '.$total.'</a>';


            // if single product in cart
            if($qty==1)
                echo '<a href="'.$cart_url.'">1 Produkt - '.$total.'</a>';
        ?>  
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

To repeat my headline: **How do I add AJAX-functionality to that cart?**

I already have an add-to-cart.js file that runs with every loop.

**edit01:**
Here's the add-to-cart.php as well:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly ?>
<?php
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button btn btn-default btn-theme-default btn-cart %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Comment: https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/woocommerce-add-to-cart-with-quantity-and-ajax/

Comment: I have that one open since.. I don't know 10 days ago. I can't get it to work for some reason. Feels like either me or the snippet is missing something.